# Cyclic modular sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Let $n\geq2$ be an integer. Prove that for any integer $m$, $$m^{\phi(n)}\equiv(m+\text{rad}(n))^{\phi(n)}\mod n$$
Note: $\phi(n)$ is the Euler Totient function and $\text{rad}(n)$ is the radical of an integer.

I know that when $n$ is a square-free, this problem is trivial. I can't seem to figure out how to handle the case when $n$ is not square-free.

Comment: If $m,n$ are coprime then so are $m+\text{rad}(n),n$ and it is easy. Then assume it is true for $l$ and look at $m = pl$ for $p | n$